# Convergence of $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+3}{3x_n+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $0<x_1<1$. Define $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+3}{3x_n+1}$ for $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ 
Prove that $(x_n)$ converges.

I have shown that the above sequence is a positive real number sequence by induction. Further, I can show that if the sequence converges, then the limit of the sequence is $1$.

Also, the sequence is not monotonic.
For e.g.: if $x_1=\frac{1}{3}$, then $x_2=\frac{5}{3}$, $x_3=\frac{7}{8}$, $\cdots$
In general, if $x_{n+1}<1\Rightarrow x_{n}>1$. Moreover, it is easy to see that for all $x_1\in (0,1)$, we have $x_2>1$.

Please provide me hints to show that the sequence converges. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include some terms of the sequence to see how non monotonic it is

Comment: $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n-1})$ are monotonic.

Comment: @jimjim Please see the edit.

Comment: Let $x_n = 1 + \delta_n$.  Can you find the expression for $\delta_{n+1}$ as a function of $\delta_n$?  It should be clear that $|\delta_n |$ decreases monotonically to zero.

Comment: From what I can see the series oscillates between being greater and less than one, and as you move forward converges to 1. I agree with @mjqxxxx

Comment: Note that a totally different approach would be to apply the Banach fixed point theorem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568829

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n-1})$ are monotonic (as mentioned by you in your comment).

Check that $0< x_n <4$ for all $n$. So $(x_{2n})$ and $(x_{2n-1})$ are both convergent. If the limits are $l $ and $m$ then $l=\frac {m+3} {3m+1}$ and $m=\frac {l+3} {3l+1}$. What does this give?